# The exact meaning of root view controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I read the following from Apple official doc [*Start Developing iOS Apps*](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementNavigation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH16-SW1):

> The set of view controllers managed by a particular navigation controller is called its navigation stack. The first item added to the stack becomes the root view controller and is never popped off (removed from) the navigation stack.

But in another official doc by Apple [*View Controller Programming Guide for iOS*](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TheViewControllerHierarchy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH33-SW1) and many other documents on the net I read that root view controller is the controller of root view, the first view added to window.

> The root view controller is the anchor of the view controller hierarchy. Every window has exactly one root view controller whose content fills that window.

So, in the navigation view controller case, shouldn't navigation view controller be root view controller? How come the first doc above says that its child view controller is root view controller? Am I missing something? Thanks for any explanation.

Comment: I agree completely that the use of the same term for two quite different things (“root” of what, exactly?) is unfortunate. It isn’t a problem in practice, however.

Comment: @matt It is a problem for beginners like me in practice because I had to stop reading and asked for clarification on SO :) That said, I'm glad I got help from guys here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixing two different things. In case of `navigation stack` root controller is at root of the stack but in the case of `window`, `rootViewController` is the first view controller that appears when your app launch. Though in both cases you can change root.

Again in case of `navigationController` when you are saying it own should be root rather than its first child, you basically falsifying the first statement from apple which is true, you can't pop a navigation's root. Navigation Controller is not a usual controller we play with, it act like a container which hold whole stack of controllers routed in it. You can go back and forth but no back after `rootViewController`.

Both are different things referenced with same name. I think navigation's rootViewController came in iOS way before than window's came. Though it's somewhat correct reference name, wants to change the whole hierarchy of app change active window's root same as wants to change whole navigation stack, change the navigation's root.

Comment: if I understand what you said correctly, authors of the two docs used the phase ("root view controller") for different meaning, right? That's what I thought before I posted the question. If so, that's very confusing and I don't understand why UIKit document writers would do it this way. In addition, I don't think it's accurate to say "rootViewController is the first view controller that appears when your app launch". In my opinion, root view controller is the controller of the first direct view of window.

Comment: Thanks. That's the confirmation I'm looking for.